# How would you automate downloading a file from a site everyday using python?

Tags: python, file, download, web-scraping

How to automate the download a file from this page https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm, I tried it using python using urllib.

```
import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/JUN?cm23JUN2017bhav.csv.zip8", "file.zip8")
```

Even that doesn't seem to work I don't know why but how do you go about downloading file from such a site with changing uri to files, just see pattern and add code like in the above case using *dates*? and why doesn't the above code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `urllib.URLopener()`, just use `urllib.urlretrieve()` instead as the following:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/JUN?cm23JUN2017bhav.csv.zip8", "file.zip8")
```

You can also use `wget`:

```
import wget
wget.download("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/JUN?cm23JUN2017bhav.csv.zip8", "file.zip8")
```

And about automating it to download everyday, you can either use windows scheduler, or use a `loop` as the following:

```
import urllib
import time
while True:
    urllib.urlretrieve('file', 'file')
    time.sleep(86400) # 86400 seconds = 24 hours.
```

Comment: Thanks buddy and if you see the uri of the file is changed everyday? how do you update that!

Comment: What exactly do you want to update?

Comment: No I mean inorder to download a file you got to have a specific URI right ? And that in the site I mentioned gets changed everyday. I just want to know how to code that in

Comment: Do you know the pattern? or will you know the URL each day and want to update it?